# Intellij Idea12 Failed to clear URL cache

Tags: java, caching, intellij-idea

I just installed ubuntu 13.10 x64 on my laptop, i proceeded to install Intellij Idea12, which is running perfectly on my 32bit system, both machines having java 1.7.0_45 from oracle.
When i run Idea.sh on the x64 from the terminal i get:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
Failed to clear URL cache
```

If i run it as sudo i get the same output but it starts, tho i would really like to know what the issue is, i have invalidated the caches (Files->Invalidate caches) with Intellij-Idea started as sudo, and also removed all the caches manually but the problem persists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also get the same message, but it appears to be normal. Because I just did a clean install, my guess is that there is no URL cache to clear. Using: CrunchBang 11 64bit w/Java 8

Comment: After a couple of reboots the problem went away, don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

You may already have one instance of IDEA running. Go ahead and check:

```
$ ps -ef | grep idea
```

Use `kill` or `kill -9` to stop that instance then try restarting it.